# Tag Synonym Request: [processes] -> [process]?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [processes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/processes) is just a pluralization of the [process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/process) tag. Seems like they could be synomized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great suggestion. Pluralisations should always be synonyms yes. I've created and approved it.